# How to get Server connected?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to build a chat app from a Youtube tutorial and I can't get 'Server connected', only "Server running".
My project is here https://danclaudiu95@bitbucket.org/danclaudiu95/chat-app-io.git
The server.js contains:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
    usernames = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server Running...');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Socket Connected...');

    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
        if(usernames.indexOf(data) != -1){
            callback(false);
        } else {
            callback(true);
            socket.username = data;
            usernames.push(socket.username);
            updateUsernames();
        }
    });

    // Update Usernames
    function updateUsernames(){
        io.sockets.emit('usernames', usernames);
    }

    // Send Message
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: data, user:socket.username});
    });

    // Disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        if(!socket.username){
            return;
        }

        usernames.splice(usernames.indexOf(socket.username), 1);
        updateUsernames();
    });
});
```

Can anyone point me what am I doing wrong?

On server.js file, the line "var express = require('express')," is dotted at the word "require".

Comment: The link to your project seems to be dead.

Comment: Try this https://bitbucket.org/danclaudiu95/chat-app-io/src/master/

Comment: put your code in your question. Though your issue is `io.sockets.on('connection',` should be `io.on('connection',`

Comment: I edited my question.  After putting io.on instead of io.socket.on I get 'throw new Error(msg);
    ^'

Answer (score 0):

Remove requiring `http`. Express already do that for you.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    usernames = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server Running...');

//.. The rest of your code
```

Comment: Tried with your code, it gives me " io = require('socket.io').listen(server);                               
ReferenceError: server is not defined"  and when I replace "server" with "app" in  "io = require('socket.io').listen(server);"  it gives me  throw new Error(msg);
    ^
Error: You are trying to attach socket.io to an express request handler function. Please pass a http.Server instance.
I run the application by command "node server.js".

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice that you are using server in socket.io, i returned server back but the issue was that you should not listen to server but to express app.

Comment: I added the code from server.js to my question. I can't figure out what to edit more exactly. I am gettting "throw new Error(msg);" when I edit something.